# Google apps for business report mail sent and received

Tags: google-apps-email

I would like a SMTP style log of all individual mails sent and received for a domain on Google Apps, so I can see non deliverables sent through etc. Doesn't seem to exist, or even possible. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

It actually is possible if you use the Email Audit API

The reference is here:

- [Email Audit API](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/audit/docs/1.0/audit_developers_guide_protocol.html)

There is another API that could be useful as well: [Google Reporting API](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/reporting/google_apps_reporting_api.html)

Comment: I read: The Google Apps Email Audit API allows Google Apps administrators to audit a user's email, email drafts, and archived chats. In addition, a domain administrator can retrieve account login information and download a user's mailbox. This does not look like a sent & received log for the domain

Comment: For the Reporting API: lets you retrieve usage reports for your domain's hosted accounts.  I don't see any possibilty sent/receive log on the domain level either, apart from the fact that it looks hard too set up for a non-expert on API's.

Comment: Am a bit disappointed I cannot vote down on answers on my own question. Wonder who voted this up.

Comment: Within the Email Audit API there is a `outgoingEmailMonitorLevel` variable that you can pass. While the question you asked is if there is a way to see an SMTP log style of emails for your domain, the quick answer would be no. However, the answer I provided gives you a way to create that log yourself via Email Audit API.

Comment: TX, when I have time I might give it a try. I wonder if it logs  forwarded mail not coming from users.